# Generating PDFs - Approach to store the generating code

Tags: ruby, pdf, eval

I'm currently writing an rails application that generates some PDFs. The generated documents are things like proposals, invoices, order confirmations etc.

My intention is to provide 2 default layouts and to allow the user to request a custom layout. The user will never even see the generator code, this is all handled by trusted persons -> security is no concern at all.

My requirements:

- Easy to change / add new generators (for developers, users never see those generators)
- No redeployment
- Works well with any number of generators

The way I see it, implementing those generators as regular classes in .rb files in the source code falls flat (redeployment required, file clutter with enough of them).

I'm currently thinking about the following and would like some input into the viability / better ways to do it:

The generator code is stored in the database and whenever a document is to be printed, the code is evaled in a scope where all the relevant variables are already set (document (-> line items | customer ..), pdf, user etc.) and the generator code just uses them.

My questions is basically: Is this the way to do it and if that's the case, are there some things I should be aware of?